# How can I capture an error message I throw using the JavaScript block in ElectroNeek Studio Pro

Tags: javascript, error-handling, automation, console.log, rpa

When I use the JavaScript block I want to be able to capture an error message I throw using the red error exit bubble on the JavaScript Activity. Right now whatever string I put in the throw always comes back as “error”. I do not find it desireable to save another variable in the block as an error message outside of the throw.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzMuW.png)

I would expect the console log to have the custom error message and not error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question, I would recommend you try using: **throw Error("Some custom error message")**. This should work.
You can also follow our forum for more information on this: [Here](https://forum.electroneek.com)